# What event to look for...when changing currentTime of video element

Tags: javascript, html5-video

When i change video element current time to a point where it hasn't buffered the video stops playing. And i want to know when it starts playing as soon as the first frame.

I have tried canplay and playing without success.

Tho i did get it to work by using play and pause.

So when i pause it canplay event works and then i listen for it and which tells me that at new position at which i paused now can be played. Then i just play it however. Is it, should be, possible to do it without pausing. Why there is no readystatechange as in ajax. If video is paused,stopped,waiting for buffering(as in my case) fire an event.

Comment: omg an answer would be Very Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This list of all media element events should be helpful:
http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#event-definitions

The `waiting` and `playing` events should be relevant if you're just playing and the video pauses by itself. `waiting` fires when the video is forced to pause because it's buffering data from the network, and `playing` fires when it's ready to resume. It's worth noting the difference between `play` and `playing`. `play` fires when it's "trying" to play, i.e. `.paused === false`. But `playing` means that it's *actually* playing (although there are some weird cases where that's not strictly true, as noted in the linked document).

However, if you're seeking, you could use the `seeking` and `seeked` events. What I would do is keep a listener on all four events as well as `canplay`, and check the `.readyState` property in there.

Comment: it was terribly hard, but i had figured it out after trying almost all events...I tried seeking, stalled, canplay, durationchange, canplaythrough, suspend, and even playing. What worked was seeked. I was trying to get snapshots of video to canvas all the rest either resulted in none, same or error.  Duration change is too slow/wide. most events dont work as you would expect them to by their definition reliably.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the `timeupdate` event for media elements.

> The `timeupdate` event is fired when the time indicated by the `currentTime` attribute has been updated.

```js
addEventListener("timeupdate", (event) => {
    // Do whatever you want
});
```

Detailed version here: [MDN/timeupdate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/timeupdate_event)